# Get the id of the current view in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

Suppose we have a  model named '`repertoire`' with a  field `Many2many` '`documents_id`'
[image]

and i have a button in the many2many tree view ,in that button i want to get the id of the '`repertoire`' i'm in
is there any solution for this

Comment: Can you show me where exactlly the button placed ?

Comment: mu button is in the tree table  of documents ,,i found a way  i will post my answer  if you ever need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer ,we can pass a context to the `many2many` field ,for example :

```
<field name="app_ids" string="Apps" context="{'current_instance_id': id}">
                  <tree editable="false" create="false" delete="true">
                    <field name="name"/>
                      <button type="object" name="updating_module" icon="fa-refresh"/>

                  </tree>
                </field>
```

on my function i can retrieve it :

```
def updating_module(self):
    instance_id = self.env.context.get('current_instance_id')
```